# how to get hard disk serial number with php on localhost

Tags: php, javascript, hardware

is there a way i can get hard disk serial number or machine serial number with php or javascript on localhost ??

we can get it with following command in cmd

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber
```

or machine serial number by this

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

is that possible with php or javascript ??
something in php

```
<?php

echo DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber //** some thing like this on local host

?>
```

Need is to give a project to Clint on local host, and i want no one to access it on other computer (in php)

Comment: Not possible! Otherwise would be a big security flaw!

Comment: What does "on localhost" mean? On the *server* or on the *client*?

Comment: In IE you can use ActiveX.. the user will have to give permission for this to execute. Maybe there is a possibility?

Comment: @WouterdeKort This will most likely need to be browser compatible

Comment: Make an application and ask the users to download an run it?

Comment: Its not possible. Check some inputs here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709108/getting-serial-number-of-the-hard-drive-provided-by-the-manufacturer-through-php

Comment: @deceze its local host on my pc

Comment: You can of course use `shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1')` or `shell_exec('wmic bios get serialnumber 2>&1')` if wmic is installed on server and your PHP has permission to run it.

The '2>&1' part is used from the [suggestion here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250).

Comment: @Lenin thx bro it worked ... can u make it and not comment so i can accept it and close this question

Comment: Great that it worked. I do not have wmic installed so I couldn't check it myself.

Comment: @Harinder That doesn't mean anything. In web programming, you're either talking about **the server** or **the client**. It doesn't matter whether that's your own computer or both are the same machine or not.

Comment: @deceze Sorry its server .... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can of course use

```
shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1')
```

or

```
shell_exec('wmic bios get serialnumber 2>&1')
```

if `wmic` is installed on server and your PHP has permission to run it.

The `'2>&1'` part is used from the [suggestion here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250).

Comment: And just a FYI, shell_exec has a variant with [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) in php.

Answer (score 2):

impossblie. Nothing can break the browser sandbox, otherwize it will be a big security problem.

The only possibility is via ActiveX , but still need to signature and change the IE settings. (no cross platform, not cross browser)