# How to get the client HDD serial number over the web for license key generation?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to generate licenses for every client that makes request to my api.
Is there  a way to do it using the hard disk serial number.

Details : API written in php

Comment: not going to happen with JavaScript

Comment: I believe so looking for days

Comment: Well the browser does not have this information so you can not do it.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797030/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-with-php-on-localhost)

Comment: Nope I'm not running anything locally the client runs javascript and makes ajax calls to a php api

Comment: Can't be done, the browser has no access to the clients computer, and certainly not the hardware itself. Best you can do is [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, modern browsers simply do not send any HDD serial number or S.M.A.R.T. info.

Comment: Why did someone neg this?  It's the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Because of privacy issues, you as the API generator cannot know much about the user besides the `ipaddress` and the `browser type`.  I would recommend you store a cookie for each user such as

```
 $_COOKIE['Mystuff'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].rand(10000);
```

And that will give you a unique fingerprint for that machine / location.

Comment: `rand(10000)` doesn't really give you a unique id, it's even guaranteed you would get two different values for just two different users. There is something called `uniqid` in PHP for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

One can use a bat file say  "getHDDNum.bat" as below

```
@ECHO OFF
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber>C:/Users/pk/Desktop/HardDriveNum.txt
```

This will write the number to text file--> HardDriveNum.txt

The bat file can be uploaded to server and user asked to download and run it.

User then reads the generated txt file and enter the number in form input box.

cheers

jayk